# Make app on cydia private?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a way to make an app on the cydia repos private so that others cant see it or use it?

Or is there another way to privately push apps to a device without going through something like the enterprise app program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your app as a .deb package (all packages on Cydia are in .deb format), you can install the locally with the dpkg tool. Also, e.g. iFile allows that with an UI.

If you do this more often, you could setup a private (= not known to other) repository and have your users add it manually to Cydia. By that, they would get notified about updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the user's IP address, you could block it. But I'm not sure if that's the IP that Cydia uses when it gets the package. If you want it completely inaccessible, then just block all IPs except yours.